# Flexible control validation

Tags: typescript, angular

I am new to angular and I'd like to know if it is possible to make validations more flexible by passing parameters to them. E.g. a decimal validation where you can have 2 (3 or 4 in other cases) decimal places.

I have this ng-book 2 and there is this example:

```
function skuValidator(control: Control): { [s: string]: boolean } {
   if (!control.value.match(/^123/)) {
       return {invalidSku: true};
   }
}
```

-

```
this.myForm = fb.group({
   'sku': ['', Validators.compose([
   Validators.required, skuValidator])]
});
```

As you can see the only parameter I get is the control parameter. It would be nice if I could switch validation in the same validator. For one control there are only integers allowed and for the other control decimal places are allowed too. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**function that returns a validator function**

Just create a function that takes the parameters and returns the validator function

```
function skuValidator(param) {
  function validate(control: Control): { [s: string]: boolean } {
     // use `param` value in validator
     if (!control.value.match(/^123/)) {
         return {invalidSku: true};
     }
  }
  return validate;
}
```

get the validator like:

```
this.myForm = fb.group({
   'sku': ['', Validators.compose([
   Validators.required, skuValidator(someValueFromComponent)])]
});
```

**class that returns a validator function**

Alternatively you can also create class

```
class SkuValidator {
  constructor(private:param) {}

  validate(control: Control): { [s: string]: boolean } {
     // use `param` value in validator
     if (!control.value.match(/^123/)) {
         return {invalidSku: true};
     }
  }
}
```

get the validator like:

```
this.myForm = fb.group({
   'sku': ['', Validators.compose([
   Validators.required, new SkuValidator(someValueFromComponent).validate])]
});
```